# How to call a datetimepicker ? Object doesn't support this property

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I am trying to call a datetime picker ..how to do it ?

i am referring this link

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

And i have included .js files as below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JqgridAction.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MVCControls/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MVCControls/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MVCControls/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MVCControls/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    alert($("#example1").length);
        $('#example1').datetimepicker();
    });  
</script>
```

And this is my body:

```
<div class="blueline">
    <div align="left">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please correct the following errors")
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {   
             <div class="example-container">
                <p>
                    Add a simple timepicker to jQuery UI's datepicker</p>
                <div>
                    <input id="example1" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" value="" name="example1" />
                </div>              
            </div>

            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        }

</div>
```

I am getting error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

show code below:at the line $('#example1').datetimepicker();

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/JqgridAction.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MVCControls/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MVCControls/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MVCControls/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MVCControls/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#example1').datetimepicker(); 
    });  
</script>
```

I can see the render text box, after i ignore error, but i cannot get the calender when i focus the mouse inside the text box.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use jQuery in noConflict mode. 
[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

The error occurs when you are using diffrent client libery that will attacth itself to the $ variable

Comment: Thanks its worked .... but the calendar is not showing in the text box ..can you asist for that as well...?

Comment: Do you got any errors? If you just execute the this line in the console in Chrome: $('#example1').datetimepicker(); What does it return?

Comment: I got a response in the console of "[input#startTime.hasDatepicker]" (I changed example1 to startTime) and when I hover over it, Firebug highlights the text input field. However, I get no picker upon selecting the text field.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you have something wrong in your CSS references? Try to find the calender in the DOM. It will be before the closing body tag. You will have to use Firebug and inspect the element. A div with this class should apper: <div class="ui-datepicker-div ****

Comment: A search in the DOM didn't find anything like that.  I did see this though: " <div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>".  Is there some event that I should be registering/catching?  Thanks... Here are my CSSs:   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui.dynatree.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.cluetip.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css"/>

Comment: For those that are interested, the answer is that you must have your jQuery and HTML exactly as in the examples (not sure why).  So, must have DIV and PRE and ...  Best of luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>jQuery Datepicker Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.ui-datepicker    
        {
            font-size: 10px;
        }
    </style>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtDateFrom,#txtDateTo').datepicker({
                changeYear: true,
                beforeShow: function (textbox, instance) {
                    instance.dpDiv.css({
                        marginTop: (-textbox.offsetHeight) + 'px',
                        marginLeft: textbox.offsetWidth + 'px'
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <form id="testForm" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtDateFrom" /><br />
            <input type="text" id="txtDateTo" />
        </div>
     </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what actually u mean? ..this is not i needed ..i want a mvc code

Answer (score 0):

try putting the.js files in /script folder directly 
i.e 
instead of

```
<script src="/Scripts/MVCControls/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

try

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

cut paste the jquery .js files accordingly and this may work in this folder structure

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$('#example1').datetimepicker();
```

Should be:

```
$('#example1').datepicker();
```

Additionally you could try the compatibility version like this:

```
var jQuery = $.noConflict();
jQuery('#example1').datepicker();
```